# arrogant slow gait

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrases, idiomatic-language, literature

```
ANNABEL and Midge came out of the tearoom with the arrogant slow gait of the leisured, for their Saturday afternoon stretched ahead of them.
```

Hey there,
What does this text mean by "the arrogant slow gait of the leisured" does that resemble snobbish style of walking in this context or else?

Comment: Yes, that is about right.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the literal meaning is that the way they walked was the way that snobs walk.

It is perhaps difficult to understand because it does not make much sense when interpreted literally. It assumes two generalizations. First, those who enjoy an unusual degree of leisure typically feel contempt toward the rest of humanity, and, second, such contempt is typically evinced by an unusually slow style of walking.

Do those unemployed typically feel contempt for those employed? Do those with more leisure typically walk in an unusual way?

The intended meaning was probably more along the lines of

> They left the tearoom assuming the stately pace of aristocrats at leisure.